# Merge DispatcherServlet and MessageDispatcherServlet

Tags: spring-ws

Is there a way in which we can merge `org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet`
and `org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet`

They both are for different purpose, but I want to merge them into one single servlet. So that I can simply put a URL-Matching to `/*` and every call can go from one servlet.

Below `web.xml` works fine but I want to change the URL matching for *spring-ws* to `/*`

```xml
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/page</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring-ws</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>transformWsdlLocations</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-ws</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Any idea on this?

Answer (score 5):

[5.3.2. **Wiring up Spring-WS in a DispatcherServlet**](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/server.html#d5e908).

I think that's exactly what you want to do.